# jquery mmenu from frebsite doesn't work in landscape orientation on mobile (android)

Tags: android, jquery, menu, mmenu

ok, so I'm using this plugin for a website I'm developing and I came across a tricky bug. the menu won't work on android on landscape orientation. when one of the buttons who trigger the expanding menu is pushed (tapped) the menu opens, but when I try to tap to collapse it back it won't work. I've tested on several android versions and a couple of android mobile devices (htc, samsung) and the result is the same. I even tried this link from the website (the example page) on this android devices and the bug is also [there](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/demo/advanced.html).

any ideas?

Comment: Your link is broken. Try posting the code so that we can see it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug on my Android device based on their page. Do you have link to your site?